# Iterate N items at a time on a generator with single yield

Tags: python-3.x

How do I do that?
islice() return n items at a time but I can't figure out how to iterate it.
Right now I do something like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
   print 3 lines at a time.
'''

def myread(filename):
  with open(filename,'r',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    for line in f:
        yield line.strip()

filename = 'test.txt'
temp = []
for res_a in myread(filename):
  temp.append(res_a)
  if len(temp)==3:
    print(temp)
    temp = []
print(temp)
```

Note that I don't know how big is my text file.

Comment: Can you just do: `with open('file') as fin: lines = list(itertools.islice(fin, 3))` ?

Comment: @asynts ops. i'm porting from 2.7 so I might do similar mistakes..

Comment: @JonClements no, the file is huge and I'd like not to change the file reader.Also I might use something else instead of that reader. Or use it with less fetches. It's for using with parallel processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.islice` and the two argument form of `iter`, eg:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('file') as fin:
    # gen-comp yielding stripped lines
    lines = (line.strip() for line in fin)
    # create list of at most 3 lines from the file's current position 
    # and use an empty list as a sentinel value of when to stop... (no more lines)
    for three in iter(lambda: list(islice(lines, 3)), []):
        print(three)
```

As a function:

```
def myread(filename): 
    with open(filename) as fin:
        lines = (line.strip() for line in fin)
        yield from iter(lambda: list(islice(lines, 3)), [])
```

Comment: The file is huge. I prefer to use a generator. I'm not sure if your code read just part of the file.

Comment: It reads 3 lines at a time... apart from building a list of three lines - there's no other memory usage here...

Comment: add-on question: how do you put it in a function? it would be enough to return a list. I was wondering if i could use just the list(isslice) part, but I miss elements (my file has 4 lines)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "miss elements" - if you've got 4 lines - you'll get 2 iterations (one list with 3 elements and one with 1)?

Comment: I did a mistake on my adaptation. I didn't get the second iteration, basically. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`islice(itr, n)` will only return an iterator that runs until it reaches the `n`th element of `itr`.  You would have to keep rebuilding the `islice` iterator for every group of `n` elements you want to return.  You might want to try the `grouper` recipe from [the itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), which avoids this rebuilding:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

---

To complete the example, you can filter out the `fillvalue`s added to the output groups to get it to replicate the code provided by the OP:

```
for grp in grouper(myread(filename), 3):
    trimmed_grp = [line for line in grp if line is not None]
    print(trimmed_grp)
```

Comment: One could use this... but if the file is only 4 lines (or any other number not divisible by three) - then the very last group needs filtering out for the fillvalue's...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  Added an example way to deal with that, though dealing with it directly in the `grouper` function is probably a more efficient solution.