# python3 using a generator to filter file with multiline records

Tags: python, file, generator, subset, multiline

I need to read huge files structured as multiline records and write to a file records with certain indices, say record numbers R = 1, 2 and 1093.
If records are N = 3 lines each this amounts to reading the file line by line and then write lines numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4, 5, 6 and 3277, 3278, 3279 (in that the first line in each record Ri starts at line number Ri-1 * N + 1.

I guess one could calculate the lines to write and go through the file line by line and write those lines. However, is it possible to "zip" consecutive lines 1, 2 and 3 into a generator object containing records and filter these somehow or would or print them directly to file if they enumerate to R ?
Something along this pseudocode :

```
def subset(file_in, file_out, N, R):
    with open(file_in, "rt") as fin, open(file_out, "wt") as fout:
        line = (line.rstrip() for line in fin)
        record = enumerate(zip(line, line, line)) # What if records are of size N
        for i, r in record if i in R:
            fout.write(r)
```

What to do if you want the record size N as parameter ?

**UPDATE EXAMPLE**

An example for file_in (4 records, 3 lines/record):

```
dslfkj
2
a
dflkj
3
g
fds
2
b
fsdlkj
1
n
```

Then subset(file_in, file_out, 3, [1,3]) would give (file_out)

```
dslfkj
2
a
fds
2
b
```

Comment: XY problem. you do not need to group or collect these lines to be able to get this output.

Comment: No then I would need to calculated the lines to print (as mentioned in my question intro) right ?

Comment: mhm, that is definitely cleanest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969335/iterate-n-items-at-a-time-on-a-generator-with-single-yield ... How about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate N items at a time on a generator with single yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969335/iterate-n-items-at-a-time-on-a-generator-with-single-yield)

Comment: @Suparshva I think that one does not select specific records (but I could have misread that post.

Comment: @user3375672 from your code you seem to get n lines at a time (which you consider record ... first n lines record 1, next n lines record 2 and so on) ... now you need specific records say 1, 3 7 (correct me if I have understood wrong) ... so once you have generator as in answer and you can then have another generator which yields those 1,3 and 7 records (take it as input list) ... the record number you can keep track how many times have you performed yield to the first generator ... your question asked "What to do if you want the record size N as parameter ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, it makes sense just to tackle this directly line by line, using floor division.

For Example:

```
fin = '''
dslfkj
2
a
dflkj
3
g
fds
2
b
fsdlkj
1
'''

line_gen = (line.rstrip() for line in fin.strip().split())

R = [1, 3]
R = [val - 1 for val in R] #zero indexing
N = 3
for i, line in enumerate(line_gen):
    if i // N in R:
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
dslfkj
2
a
fds
2
b
```

Your function can look something like follows: (you may want to check if it works out of the box or requires tweaks. i did not check the file opening portion.

```
def subset(file_in, file_out, N, R):
    R = [val - 1 for val in R] #zero indexing
    with open(file_in, "rt") as fin, open(file_out, "wt") as fout:
        line_gen = (line.rstrip() for line in fin)
        for i, line in enumerate(line_gen):
            if i // N in R:
                fout.write(line)
                fout.write('\n')
```

---

Edit: The answer below pertains to how you could use the generators and group the values together. Having said that, i do not think you should need to use it. However, if you still wish to, you can construct your function based off of it.

Old answer:

You can create `n` references to the object using list, and then unpack using the [`*` (aka splat) operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

For example:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
line = (x for x in range(100, 132))
n = 3
record = zip(*([line] * n)) #equivalent to *[line, line, line] which is unpacked into zip arguments
for i, r in enumerate(record):
    print(i, r)

0 (100, 101, 102)
1 (103, 104, 105)
2 (106, 107, 108)
3 (109, 110, 111)
4 (112, 113, 114)
5 (115, 116, 117)
6 (118, 119, 120)
7 (121, 122, 123)
8 (124, 125, 126)
9 (127, 128, 129)
```

Also, depending on what you want to happen for "leftover" lines, you may want to use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) instead.

Comment: Exactly - maybe your function needs a newline in write()

Comment: Slightly more neat perhaps with a single line `print(line, file = fout)`