# Iterate over all the sub-groups of a list

Tags: python, list, numpy

Let's say I have a list `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, and I want to iterate over all the subgroups of len 2 `[1,2] [3,4] [5,6]`.

The naive way of doing it

```
    L = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    N = len(L)//2
    for k in range(N):
        slice = L[k*2:(k+1)*2]
        for val in slice:
            #Do things with the slice
```

However I was wondering if there is a more pythonic method to iterate over a "partitioned" list already. I also accept solutions with `numpy arrays`. Something like:

```
    L = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    slices = f(L,2) # A nice "f" here? 
    for slice in slices:
        for val in slice:
            #Do things with the slice
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `np.array(L).reshape(-1,2)` makes a (n,2) array.  But this does not make the iteration any faster.  Creating the array from the list takes time, and iteration on arrays is slower.  You also need to consider whether the `Do Things` part is better with lists or arrays.

Comment: "Better" measured how?

Comment: @ScottHunter fair point. `slice = L[k*2:(k+1)*2]` is not immediate when read, that is taking a slice of a list, so I was thinking something as my second snippet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate N items at a time on a generator with single yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969335/iterate-n-items-at-a-time-on-a-generator-with-single-yield)

Comment: @Woodford either I didn't understand how to use it, or it does not do what I want, which is basically a reshape as hpaulij has pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`grouper`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe from the `itertools` library:

```py
import itertools

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

L = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for slice in grouper(L, 2):
    print(slice)
```

Comment: Upvoted. Faster than my answer, and also iterator-based.

Answer (score 1):

To have a nice `f` as you are asking (not commenting on whether it is really a good idea, depending on what you are really trying to do) I would go with `itertools`

```py
itertools.islice(itertools.pairwise(L), 0, None, 2)
```

is your `f`. Note that L is a list here. But it could be any iterator. Which is the point with itertools. You could have billions of iteration in L, and therefore billions of iterations with my generator, without using any memory. As long as L is not in memory, and that what you are doing with the slice is not stacking them in memory (if you do, then the method is just the same as any other).

Usage example

```py
import itertools
L=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for p in itertools.islice(itertools.pairwise(L), 0, None, 2):
   print(p)
```

```
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
(5, 6)
```

### Explanation

`itertools.pairwise` iterates by pairs. So almost what you are looking for.
Except that those are 'overlapping'.

In your case, it iterates `(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6)`

`itertools.islice(it, 0, None, 2)` iterates every two elements.

So both together, your get the 1st, 3rd, 5th, .. pairs of previous iterator, that is what you want

### Timings

Doing nothing, with 1000 elements

| method | Timing |
| --- | --- |
| Yours | 94 ms |
| Variant | 52 ms |
| numpy | 187 ms |
| itertools | 48 ms |
| Woodford | 42 ms |

Note: what I call "variant" is almost the same as your method (not the same timings tho!), avoiding the `k*2`

```py
for k in range(0,len(L),2):
    slice = L[k:k+2]
    for val in slice:
        ....
```

The fact that it is so fast (almost as fast as mine) says a lot about how negligible all this is. All I did is avoid 2 multiplication, and it almost halves the timing.

Note 2: numpy is inefficient in this example, precisely because we do nothing in this question but iterating. So building of the array is what costs.
But depending on what you want to do, numpy can be way faster than any other method, if you can avoid any iteration.

For example (just using a random one), if what you want to do is computing the sum for every pairs `(a,b)` of `L` of `a+2b`, `numpy`'s `a[:,0].sum()+a[:,1].sum()*2` would beats any iteration based method, even with itertools.

But, well, from what we know of your problem (that is that you want to iterate), my `itertools` method is so far the fastest. And since it is a one-liner, I guess it is also the most pythonesque.

### Edit

I stand corrected: Woodford's (also itertools, but different) method, posted while I was writing this answer, is faster.

Not a one-liner as is. But that is because they wanted to deal with case there is not a even number of elements in L, which other method did not.

Else it could also be written like this

```py
zip(*[iter(L)]*2)
```

For example

```py
for p in zip(*[iter(L)]*2):
   print(p)
```

Gives the same result as before.

(Explatation: we have 2 competing iterators for the same iterable. So each time we "consume" an element from an iterator, it is no longer available for the other. So zipping them iterates through pairs of successive elements from the initial iterator `L`, never using the same element twice).

I update my timing table.

Comment: I love this answer, thanks a lot. I need more time to study it. Am I right in understanding that what `islice` returns is not a list, but an iterator, and that is basically a reference to where the elements are, so `L` is accessed only when doing something with `p` , but not when retrieving `p` itself?

Comment: @Fra93 Yes, `islice` is an iterator. And its argument may also be an iterator (an "iterable". Which covers both iterators and lists). On a list, `islice` is not very useful. `for x in islice(it, a,b,c)` is the same as `for x in it[a:b:c]` if `it` is a list. But when `it` is an iterator itself (which is the case here, since `it` is `pairwise(L)`), it is useful.

Comment: So, here `islice(it, 0, None, 2)` just means "iterate through `it` but ignores every 2 elements".

Comment: And, yes, iterators are not lists. Just a sort of function providing elements one after another. You know one example: `range(1000)` is an iterator (it is even more than that, but it is also that). It doesn't really built a list of 1000 numbers. It is just a special sort of function that gives the next number at each call. You can `for i in range(1000000000000): print(i)` on a machine with 512 Mb of memory, and it will take an awfully long time to execute, but won't crash because of memory outage. `range(1000000000000)` is not a list of 1 trillion elements.

Comment: It is always better, when dealing with questions likes yours (how to iterate by pairs) without a priori knowledge on where the elements come from and what we want to do with them, to favor iterators, when possible, rather than building actual lists.

Comment: @Fra93. Last remark: please note that I've edited my answer. I still find my own answer interesting, because it is an opportunity to use `pairwise`, which is a recent addition to python. But Woodford's answer is even faster, and also use itertools, and also use only iterators. So I would go with their answer.